# Adding on_premise_sam_account attribute to JWT claim on azure ad

Tags: jwt, azure-active-directory

I have been trying to return onpremisessamaccountname in my id token, I can't seem to get the syntax or something right tried the following:

```
"optionalClaims": {
    "idToken": [
        {
            "name": "onprem_sam_account_name",
            "source": "user",
            "essential": true,
            "additionalProperties": []
        }
    ],

"optionalClaims": {
    "idToken": [
        {
            "name": "onprem_sam_account_name",
            "source": "user.onpremsamaccountname",
            "essential": true,
            "additionalProperties": []      }
    ],

    "optionalClaims": {
    "idToken": [
        {
            "name": "onprem_sam_account_name",
            "source": "user.onprem_sam_account_name",
            "essential": true,
            "additionalProperties": []      }
    ],
```

Answer (score 1):

onprem_sam_account_name is part of the restricted claim set in Azure AD. You cannot add it as an optional claim in the token.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-claims-mapping#table-1-json-web-token-jwt-restricted-claim-set

Comment: I've seen this but I have been able to add other attributes from the list..The site states... Restricted claim set Can't be modified using policy. The data source cannot be changed, and no transformation is applied when generating these claims. I believe I within the rules.

Comment: @JustinCox Were you able to figure this out? I know how to modify the AzureAD policy through Powershell and get the samAccountName in the ID Token .. but not the Access Token which i'm looking for...

Answer (score 1):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-jwt-claims-customization

See the link above for full details. In short, the claim needs to be added to the *enterprise application*. Once done the new claim will be sent with the id token for the *application* when a user logs in.

> To edit claims, open the application in Azure portal through the Enterprise Applications experience. Then select Single sign-on blade in the left-hand menu and open the Attributes & Claims section.

EDIT: You'll probably also need to set `"acceptMappedClaims": true,` in the *application* manifest.

[image: Manage claim]

[image: Claims]